# OkHttp how to listen for timeout?

Tags: android, okhttp

I've got this:

```
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(someUrl)
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I have looked at https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#timeouts

I tried adding:

```
    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

To the `OkHttpClient` builder, but I did not notice any difference even when I set the timeout number to 1 second.

Is there some way to listen for a timeout? What should I expect to happen if that timeout value is exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

If the request times out, it’ll fail with an IOException. This will happen either when you call `execute()` or when you read the response body.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue before. I solve the problem using the Asynchronous request's onFailure() callback. if Asynchronous suits you give it a try.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#asynchronous-get
https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/okhttp_25/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Callback.java#L20-#L26